# Radio button tag can not be checked

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Radio button tag can not  be checked

I totally have no idea why the radio button can not be clicked.

I use contants to generate the radio buttons

## haml ERB

```
            - User::NOTIFY_POLICY.each do |type|
              .radio.radio-info.radio-inline
                = f.radio_button :notify_policy, type
                = f.label :notify_policy, type
```

## html

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" value="on_price_change" checked="checked" name="user[notify_policy]" id="user_notify_policy_on_price_change">
                <label for="user_notify_policy">on_price_change</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" value="only_lowest_price_appears" name="user[notify_policy]" id="user_notify_policy_only_lowest_price_appears">
                <label for="user_notify_policy">only_lowest_price_appears</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: nothing wrong with the html it's letting me select buttons. Any js being run that might be blocking it?

Comment: it's really wired problem ~~sad